# How to create a glow effect around a UITableView group section?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I'm currently using the code below to add a border and glow around a UIButton. I would like to get the same effect around each section in a grouped UITableView. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for how I could do this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
button.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0x334962 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
button.clipsToBounds = NO;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
button.layer.borderWidth = 3;
button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
button.layer.shadowOpacity = .2;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0x273848 alpha:1.0000].CGColor;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use that....
    Your values are between 0 and 255. Use them to create a UIColor:

```
float r; float g; float b; float a;

[UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.f
            green:g/255.f
             blue:b/255.f    
            alpha:a/255.f];
```

Comment: Yea but how do you get access to the section background layer? I can get access to the tablecell background but can't figure out how to get to the section background.